# Add a suffix column names in pandas data frame with repeated name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

If I try to add a column `df["x"] = ["d","e","f"]` to this df:

```
     x    
0    a     
1    b     
2    c
```

It will just override that df:

```
   x
0  d
1  e
2  f
```

But instead of replacing that column, how can pandas add a suffix in the column name if a duplicated column name is detected when i try to add a column? So the end result will be automatically:

```
   x_0  x_1
0  a    d
1  b    e
2  c    f
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_column(df, col, data):
    if col in df.columns:
        df[f'{col}_0'] = df[col]
        df[f'{col}_1'] = data
    else:
        df[col] = data
```

Create your own function and use it like this:

```
add_column(df, "x", ["d","e","f"])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can try `join`

```
out = df.join(add, lsuffix = '_0',rsuffix='_1')
Out[361]: 
  x_0 x_1
0   a   d
1   b   e
2   c   f
#add = pd.DataFrame(["d","e","f"],columns=['x'])
```